# Запрос на получение пользовательских данных из БД MS SQL c EF. Требуется исключать пароль из объекта без использования SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, api

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        using (GrandEntities Hookup = new GrandEntities())
        {
            return Hookup.User.ToList();       
        }
    }

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        using (GrandEntities Hookup = new GrandEntities())
        {
            return Hookup.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычно пароли в открытом виде в базе не хранят, а используют хеш функцию и сохраняют результат её работы

Comment: но если вы все же решили хранить открытый пароль, то его можно исключить из результата просто создав новый класс UserDto, у которого не будет свойста Password, и при помощи AutoMapper "превращать" User -> UserDto

Comment: Пытался выполнить схожий алгоритм без этих средств, спасибо за ответ!